# RowAnnotation Font in Complex Heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap

I have a heatmap with some genes and values in dataframe. I also have a vector where the names are the same as df1 but have another identifier in the vector. I want to make a heatmap with the first df and use the identifiers in the vector as a row annotation. I have gotten this far:

```
df1

                               0-dpi      1-dpi     7-dpi    14-dpi      22-dpi
TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i2      1.27584408  0.5872404  1.780178  1.414362  1.53341851
TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i8      1.81458019  1.9002198  1.902848  1.728553  1.68079706
TRINITY_DN10214_c0_g1_i2 -2.34774378 -2.9194079 -3.211677 -2.885869 -2.04617227
TRINITY_DN10214_c0_g1_i6 -2.14867876 -1.5794957 -1.577811 -2.485095 -1.44172768
TRINITY_DN1038_c0_g1_i4   0.03163921  0.7375222  2.037936  2.462830  0.04559793
TRINITY_DN10462_c0_g1_i2 -2.63973533 -2.8039350 -2.481144 -2.698932 -1.76284020

vector

TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i2     TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i8 TRINITY_DN10214_c0_g1_i2
                   "ERF"                     "B3"            "MYB_related"
TRINITY_DN10214_c0_g1_i6  TRINITY_DN1038_c0_g1_i4 TRINITY_DN10462_c0_g1_i2
           "MYB_related"                "G2-like"                "G2-like"
```

I am successful in making the heatmap but I cannot change the font size of the row annotation. Would anybody know how to do so? Code is below:

```
ha = HeatmapAnnotation(text = anno_text(vector), which = "row", gp = gpar(fontsize = 5, fontfamily = "sans", fontface = "bold"))

heat.gen.k = Heatmap(tf.log, width = unit(4, "cm"),
                   km = 6, 
                   cluster_columns = F, 
                   show_row_names = F, 
                   row_title_rot = 0, 
                   row_title_gp=gpar(fontsize=5),
                   row_gap = unit(1.25, "mm"), 
                   name = "Log2FC", 
                   column_title = "Resistant - Susceptible",
                   column_title_gp = gpar(fontfamily = "sans", fontsize = 16), 
                   col = heat.col,
                   right_annotation = ha)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it has been over a year since this was posted.

I worked out instead of right_annotation = ha

you need to use:

row_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 5, fontfamily = "sans", fontface = "bold")

```
heat.gen.k = Heatmap(tf.log, width = unit(4, "cm"),
                 km = 6, 
                 cluster_columns = F, 
                 show_row_names = F, 
                 row_title_rot = 0, 
                 row_title_gp=gpar(fontsize=5),
                 row_gap = unit(1.25, "mm"), 
                 name = "Log2FC", 
                 column_title = "Resistant - Susceptible",
                 column_title_gp = gpar(fontfamily = "sans", fontsize = 16), 
                 col = heat.col,
                 row_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 5, fontfamily = "sans", fontface = "bold"))
```